# Pandas merge hierarchical dataframes and maintain hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas

[This github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2024) describes merging dataframes that have a mixed hierachy, and gives the solution of flattening the hierarchy to tuples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
new_df = df.groupby(['a']).agg({'b': [np.mean, np.sum]})
other_df = df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (7, 10, 6)], columns=['a', 'b', 'd'])
other_df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
print new_df
print other_df
p = pd.merge(new_df, other_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print p
```

output:

```
      b     
   mean  sum
a           
1     2    2
4     5    5

    b  d
a       
1   2  3
7  10  6

   (b, mean)  (b, sum)  b  d
a                           
1          2         2  2  3
```

However I would like to maintain the hierarchy, with a result as follows:

```
       b        b  d
    mean  sum
x                           
y      .    .   .  .
```

I just made the values dots here as they don't really make sense in this scenario, but hopefully the idea is clear.... any help gratefully received..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
>>> other_to_tup = [(x, 'val') for x in other_df.columns]
>>> other_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(other_to_tup)
>>> p = pd.merge(new_df, other_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>> p
      b              d
   mean  sum  val  val
a
1     2    2    2    3
```

Comment: Yes I am! Thanks alko :)